# Asignar valor a un input retornado de un controlador

Tags: jquery, ajax, mvc

tengo este `script` en mi vista

```html
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PlanVenta").change(function () {
            $("#Precio").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'@Url.Action("PreciosPorTipoVenta")',
                datatype:'json',
                data:{Id_Plan:$("#PlanVenta").val(),Id_Articulo:$("#Id_Articulo").val()},
                success:function(precios){
                    $("#Precio").val(?????);
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

el cual envia datos a este controlador

```html
public JsonResult PreciosPorTipoVenta(int Id_Plan, int Id_Articulo)
        {
            return Json(querty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

y tengo este input al cual le quiero asignar el valor que me retorna el controlador desde ajax

```html
<input type="text" id="Precio" name="Precio" />
```

que debo poner ahí por que ya intente poner `precios.Value` como había visto en un ejemplo pero no sale nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que te devuelve `precios` del `succcess`, puedes poner `console.log(precios);` dentro del `succcess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de [oscar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2794/oscarsolis) debería ser valida ya que recibes un `json` de esta manera `{precios:[{precio:600}]}`.

Intenta `$('#Precio').val(precios[0].precio);` ya que es posible que estés obteniendo un arreglo con mas datos

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas recorrer el json regresado, en este caso la cachas como precio, tienes que recorrer el json precio dependiendo los atributos que este tenga y que quieras mostrar en el input ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PlanVenta").change(function () {
            $("#Precio").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'@Url.Action("PreciosPorTipoVenta")',
                datatype:'json',
                data:{Id_Plan:$("#PlanVenta").val(),Id_Articulo:$("#Id_Articulo").val()},
                success:function(precios){
                    //precios es la respueta de tu contralador
                    $('#Precio').val(precios.propiedad);

                },
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: ya le intente asi pero sale en blanco igual